# Django database design choice

Tags: database, django

I have a table of Users who are permissioned to edit one of a collection of other tables (each which has a last_modified field to indicate the last time it was changed).  I have another table that tracks each change as it is made (I have a better way to track history/versioning, but this is meant more for posting a rolling list of updates to the user)

```
class WhatsNew(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    model_update = models.CharField("Database Table", max_length=100)
    object_id = models.IntegerField("Object ID")
    object_name = models.CharField("Object Name", max_length=100)
    changed = models.TextField("Fields Updated", blank=True, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Date/Time of Update", auto_now_add=True)
```

I want the user to be able to see all of the edits they have made.  I would do this by querying the above table, filtering on the author.  But in addition, I want the user to see a list of the edits they made grouped by id.  So for instance, if user 12345 edited object 2-1, then 3-2, then 2-1 again, then 4-4, I want the user to be able to see the a list (2-1, 3-2, 4-4), the time they modified the object, and the time the object was modified by anyone.

Should I capture all of this data in a separate table or try to query it from the WhatsNew table?  I think I should capture it in a new table to avoid a possibly expensive query, but I don't want to duplicate information that is already availble in the database.

Comment: Did you consider django-reversion ? If so, why didn't you decide to use it ? It does all you want out of the box: https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

Comment: I am using django-reversion.  That will let me see each edit to every object.  But I want a second list that just lists every object once, not every single time the user edited the same object.  I worry that querying all the reversions and removing the duplicates will be unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: So you want the list of last revisions by distinct object + the last revision per object that was made by the user ?

Comment: Yes, if I used reversion for this same purpose, I would query all revisions filtered by user for distinct objects and date of most recent update by that user. And then I would also pull the date of the most recent update (by any user).  So I could either use reversion for this every time, or just make another table that would either newly log a user's update of an object, or overwrite it if there was a previous object entry, and also record the timestamp.  And then separately pull the date of last update for that object by any user.

Comment: Thanks for your details. I've tried in django shell but i'm sorry to announce i didn't find a quick'n'easy way to do that. But maybe this good old saying will un-block you: "early optimisation is root of all evil". In your situation i'd probably implement it in a pure-python slow function. Then add some caching and re-caching. Then maybe background the execution of that function with django-ztaskd or django-celery or uwsgi spooler or something like that. I am eager to read responses from actually brilliant programers to your excellent question.